# SQLite .db файл перезаписывается полностью при любой операции?

Tags: android, sqlite

В своём Android приложении мне необходимо хранить большой объём данных(20-30 тыс. записей) с постоянным доступом к содержимому с возможностью частой перезаписи элементов или добавления новых записей. Я планирую использовать для этих целей SQLite и Room, но у меня возник вопрос. Так как я часто буду изменять имеющиеся данные, то, скажем, при тысяче изменениях уже существующих записей или добавлении тысячи новых записей, при полной перезаписи при выполнении каждой операции файл весом 2Мб скушает 2Гб ресурса записи карты памяти. Мне не хотелось бы так нагружать карту памяти устройства. Никто не в курсе, при работе с SQLite изменения в .db файл вносятся посредством полной перезаписи файла или изменяются только необходимые байты?
Если всё же файл перезаписывается полностью, то существуют какие-либо варианты реализации интерфейса с более избирательным изменением файлов? Можно конечно хранить все записи во временном массиве и сбрасывать их периодически на диск, но хотелось бы сохранять изменения в файл при каждом действии. Возможно есть уже какие-то готовые решения или библиотеки?

Comment: Естественно, весь файл не перезаписывается.

Comment: @Yaant А есть подтверждение вашим словам? В документации или ещё где-то?

Comment: 1) Например, [тут](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html): _All reads from and writes to the main database file begin at a page boundary and all writes are an integer number of pages in size._ 2) Там же: _terabyte-size SQLite databases are known to exist in production._ Прикиньте, сколько времени занимала бы запись в такую базу при полной перезаписи файла. 3) Ну и просто, если бы это было не так, никто никогда не стал бы использовать такую базу в мало-мальски серьезных проектах.

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо большое! Да, я и сам понимал, что файл целиком перезаписываться не будет, это логично, просто хотелось на 100% удостовериться. Ещё раз спасибо.